# How to pass rails array mysql Where IN condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have on array like  below,

```
 skills = ['ruby','Ruby on Rails'];
```

I am trying to pass array in mysql where condition like below

```
 questions =  MysqlConnection.connection.select_all("
                   SELECT questions.*,quest_answers.* FROM `questions` 
                   INNER JOIN `quest_answers` ON `quest_answers`.`question_id` = 
                  `questions`.`id` where questions.category IN (#{skills.join(', ')})")
```

But it did not work,How can pass an array to where In condition.

Error I am getting

```
  Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on rails,  Ruby)' at line 1:  SELECT questions.*,quest_answers.* FROM `questions` INNER JOIN `quest_answers` ON `quest_answers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id` where questions.category IN (Ruby on rails,  Ruby)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a *string representation* of the array to MySQL, which doesn't work. You need to insert the values in the array into the query. This can be done by escaping the skills, and joining them:

```
skills.map { |s| "'#{s}'" }.join(', ')
```

This produces `'ruby', 'Ruby on Rails'`, which is a valid argument for the IN statement.

A better approach however is to not write the raw SQL at all, but rely on ActiveRecord to generate it. This is the more maintainable and readable approach.

```
Question.joins(:quest_answers).where(category: skills)
```

Passing an array to `where` converts it automatically into a [subset condition](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions).

Comment: Hi jdno, Your answer solved my problem, Thank you very much.

Comment: What approach did you take? Raw SQL or ActiveRecord?

Comment: First I tried with ActiveRecord but it was giving data from only first table, so I took raw SQL approach. Thank you

Comment: @ManjunathC using `ActiveRecord` can give you both sets of data using `includes(:quest_answers).references(:quest_answers)` this will execute essentially the same as your raw sql but will also convert the return values to true AR objects.

Comment: Okay @engineersmnky thanks for your suggestion,I will try this.